# Transparent image over top of colour

Tags: css, png, overlay, transparent

I have a semi transparent image that I want to overlay on a colour background. Can't seem to get it to work, any help would be appreciated.

Code:

}`#pre-content{
    margin-top:60px;
    background-color: #00ADEE;
background: url(../images/bg_content_big.png) no-repeat 21px -8px;`

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure and the image? Try putting it into a jsFiddle.

Comment: please make your demo here :- http://tinkerbin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
background: #00ADEE url(../images/bg_content_big.png);
```

Comment: or use background-image separately instead of background shorthand.

Comment: Or what Alfa3eta says. OP uses `background-color` and `background` after. `background` will overwrite `background-color` i believe.